# REACT Trouble using hooks conditionally like useQuery and useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am starting to learn React, and I am getting better at using hooks respecting the Rule of Hooks, but I still make mistakes.

I am working on an app with an API and React frontend application. I am using a `RouterProvider` and a `QueryClientProvider` in this front application.

My authentication flow is the following :

- `Login.tsx` : Login page, redirects to an external Oauth2 API, and then back to `OauthCallback.tsx` with a `code`
- `OauthCallback.tsx` :
  -- Make an API request using `useApi()` custom hooks, which uses `useQuery()` itself.
  -- Then, depending on the result of the query I return loading props, error props, or if I get the `JwtToken` from my API, I return `UseSetToken.tsx` component. (I manage to understand that it is the way to conditionally use hooks in React).
- `UseSetToken.tsx` : Uses `useEffect()` and `useState()` via `useLocalStorage()` custom hook to store the token in localStorage, and return `UseGetUser.tsx`
- `UseGetUser.tsx` : Makes an API request **using useApi() again** with this time the JwtToken as BearerToken (`useApi()` make request with token if it exists in localStorage). And then it redirects to the `Friends.tsx` page.

When I logout, I remove the `token` through `useLocalStorage()`, and I am redirected to the `Login.tsx` page.

If I try to login again, I will get the following error :

```
[OauthCallback] query.data = Object { token: "validToken", login: "mylogin" } OauthCallback.tsx:21:10
[OauthCallback] query.data = Object { token: "validToken", login: "mylogin" } oauth-callback:1:2677
[UseGetUser] query user/id/rmorel undefined UseGetUser.tsx:13:10
[UseGetUser] query user/id/rmorel  undefined oauth-callback:1:2677
[UseGetUser] useEffect => setItem(token) validToken 2 UseSetToken.tsx:12:12
[UseGetUser] query user/id/rmorel undefined UseGetUser.tsx:13:10
[UseGetUser] query user/id/rmorel  undefined oauth-callback:1:2677
[UseGetUser] useEffect => setItem(token) validToken UseSetToken.tsx:12:12
**401 Unauthorized** XHRGET http://localhost:8080/api/user/id/mylogin [HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized 3ms]
```

This problem appears only when I logout, and try to login again once. The failure redirects me to the `Login.tsx` page, and if I try to log in again I succeed.

I see that the problem is that the second use of `useApi()` (and `useQuery()`) is happening before the token is set in the local storage, which gives a 401 error. **My question is : After logging out and logging in again, why is this API request happening before I set the token in local storage ?**
I try to respect the best practices when using React, so if you also think I am using hooks or state when I shouldn't I am interested in that.

Here are some parts of my code :

```
// OauthCallback.tsx

export default function OauthCallback() {
    const queryParameters = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const code = queryParameters.get('code');
    const api = useApi();
  
    const query1 = api.get('send oauth code', '/auth/42/callback', {
      params: { code: code },
      enabled: !!code,
    }) as UseQueryResult<tokenDto>;
    console.log('[OauthCallback] query.data = ', query1.data);
    if (query1.isLoading) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else if (query1.isError) {
      return <div>Is error...</div>;
    } else if (query1.data) {
      return <UseSetToken tokenDto={query1.data} />;
    } else {
      console.log('[OauthCallback] last else, return to /');
      return <Navigate to="/" />; // "/" corresponds to the Login page
    }
  }
  
  // UseSetToken.tsx :
  
  const UseSetToken = (props: { tokenDto: tokenDto }) => {
    const { setItem } = useLocalStorage();
  
    useEffect(() => {
      console.log('[UseGetUser] useEffect => setItem(token)', props.tokenDto.token);
      setItem('token', props.tokenDto.token);
    });
    return <UseGetUser token={props.tokenDto.token} login={props.tokenDto.login} />;
  };
  
  // UseGetUser.tsx :
  
  const UseGetUser = (props: { token: string; login: string }) => {
    const query = useApi().get('my user', `/user/id/${props.login}`) as UseQueryResult<userDto>;
    console.log(`[UseGetUser] query user/id/${props.login}`, query.data);
    if (query.isError) {
      return <div>Cant reach user</div>; // TO DO : handdle error
    } else if (query.isLoading) {
      return <div>Still loading...</div>;
    } else if (query.data) {
      return <UseSetUser user={query.data} />; // Set the user in the AuthContext
    } else {
      console.log('[UseGetUser] last else', query);
      return <Navigate to="/" />;
    }
  };
  
  // useLocalStorage()
  
  export function useLocalStorage() {
    const [value, setValue] = useState<string | null>(null);
  
    const setItem = (key: string, value: string): void => {
      localStorage.setItem(key, value);
      setValue(value);
    };
  
    const getItem = (key: string): string | null => {
      const value = localStorage.getItem(key);
      setValue(value);
      return value;
    };
  
    const removeItem = (key: string): void => {
      localStorage.removeItem(key);
      setValue(null);
    };
  
    return { value, setItem, getItem, removeItem };
  }
  
  // useApi()
  
  type RequestType = 'post' | 'get' | 'delete' | 'patch';
  
  interface RequestArgsType {
    data?: object;
    params?: SearchParamsOption;
    options?: object;
  }
  
  export function useApi() {
    const make_request = (
      type: RequestType,
      label: string,
      endpoint: string,
      args?: RequestArgsType,
    ) => {
      if (endpoint.startsWith('/')) endpoint = endpoint.slice(1);
  
      const method = (() => {
        switch (type) {
          case 'post':
            return api.post;
          case 'get':
            return api.get;
          case 'delete':
            return api.delete;
          case 'patch':
            return api.patch;
          default:
            return api.get;
        }
      })();
  
      return useQuery(label, async () => {
        try {
          const response = await method(endpoint, {
            json: args?.data,
            searchParams: args?.params,
            ...args?.options,
          });
          return response.json();
        } catch (err) {}
      });
    };
  
    const post = (label: string, endpoint: string, args?: RequestArgsType) =>
      make_request('post', label, endpoint, args);
    const get = (label: string, endpoint: string, args?: RequestArgsType) =>
      make_request('get', label, endpoint, args);
    const del = (label: string, endpoint: string, args?: RequestArgsType) =>
      make_request('delete', label, endpoint, args);
    const patch = (label: string, endpoint: string, args?: RequestArgsType) =>
      make_request('patch', label, endpoint, args);
    return { post, get, del, patch };
  }
```

I tried not to use `useApi()` but `fetch` for the 2nd API request to get the user, and it worked great, but I want to understand why it causes the problem, and how I could fix it.